# using statements

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, using-statement

Today I noticed a snippet of code that looks like the one below:

```
public class Test
{
    SqlConnection connection1 = 
      new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["c1"].ToString());
    SqlConnection connection2 = 
      new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["c2"].ToString());

    public void Method1()
    {
        using (connection1)
        {
            connection1.Open();
            using (SqlCommand newSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("text",connection2))
            {
            // do something       
            }         
        }
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        using (connection1)
        {
            // do something                
        }
    }
}
```

I am just wondering why would anyone want to open the connection when creating the class and not when calling the corresponding methods inside the class?

EDIT: I should have probably posted the whole code instead. So I do see where they are opening connection1, but then they are instantiating a sqlcommand with a different sql connection (connection2) which has not been opened anywhere. What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe they don't know about connection pooling?

Comment: You make the assumption that it is good code. Maybe it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line only initializes a connection object, which can later be used to open a connection to a database server.

```
SqlConnection connection1 = 
new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["c1"].ToString());
```

What I know is that using disposes of an object (and in the case of Connection objects they are automatically closed) after its scope so I wouldn't recommend such usage because it might be problematic with other object types (other than Connection) that can't be used after having their dispose called.

Comment: I agree, while the affect of `Dispose` is definitely implementation specific, I always think to myself that once you call `Dispose`, that object instance should never be used again.

Answer (score 0):

`connection1 = new SqlConnection(...)` does not really open the connection. It just creates the connection object.

You have to call `connection1.Open();` to actually open it. You can do this inside `using` statement block.

Refer to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It either

- written this way to enforce only single call to a method be performed on the class
- unintentionally confusing by throwing ObjectDisposed exception if you call 2 methods
- contains connection re-initialization code in blocks you've ommited.

Comment: I just tried the same code on DataTable objects and I was surprised that no exception was thrown (such as ObjectDisposedException) although the Disposed event fires. Any ideas why this happens?!

Comment: @MZN, same as in what? Try `SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(...);using(c){};c.Open();` which is what happens when `Method1` is called twice.

Comment: What I just found out (to my surprise) is that you can <i>still</i> use some objects after calling dispose on them directly or after using then in a <code>using</code> statement.

Comment: @MZN, yes. unfortunately there is no magic about `Dispose` method - it is just method by convention used to release/close/cleanup or otherwise make object no longer usable. In some cases (i.e. MemoryStream.ToArray call) this behavior such behavior is designed, sometimes just happens.

Answer (score 0):

The code is dangerous. 
If you call Method1 then Method2 (or visa versa) you will get an error (connection string not initialized).
The error occurs because the `using` statement will close the connection AND Disposes the object. I double checked what happens when dispose is called...the connection string is cleared (and possibly some other things I didn't notice).

> You don't want to re-use a disposed object.

The cost of instantiating a new connection object is insignificant so I would just create the object where needed, maybe with a little factory method to reduce code duplication, so change to something like:-

```
    private static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["c1"].ToString());
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            // do stuff...
        }
    }
    private void Method2()
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            // do other stuff...
        }
    }
```

Of course there are many different ways of approaching this problem, this is just one and indeed quite a simplistic one...but it is a good starting point and is safe :-)